# How to pass named functions as arguments in coffescript

Tags: coffeescript

I want the javascript code to be

```
someFunction(42, function onSuccess() {}, function onFailure() {})
```

Notice that while defining onSuccess and onFailure, I want to name them (not because it's necessary, but because it documents the code). However, I can't get coffeescript to generate this code.

For anonymous function passing I can do

```
someFunction(42,
->
// onsuccess code
->
// onfailure code
)
```

But when I tried to give names to those functions, it didn't translated as expected to Javascript

```
someFunction(42,
onSuccess : ->
// onsuccess code
onFailure : ->
// onfailure code
)
```

translates to

```
someFunction(42, { onSuccess : function () {}, onFailure : function () {} })
```

Another try

```
someFunction(42,
onSuccess ->
// onsuccess code
onFailure ->
// onfailure code
)
```

translates to

```
someFunction(42, onSuccess(function () {}), onFailure(function () {}))
```

How do I do this?

Comment: I don't think coffeescript has any way to create named functions :( Sucks for error traces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this work?

```
someFunction 42, (onSuccess = -> ), onFailure = ->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/keith_nicholas/Qdzph/

generates..

```
somefunction(42, (onSuccess = function() {}), onFailure = function() {});
```

also, this might be of interest http://kangax.github.com/nfe/

and, in the coffeescript faq, it talks about why you can't generate named functions :-

https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/FAQ

Comment: This doesn't exactly generate the output I wanted (i.e. named functions), but it does serve the job of documenting the code. It won't help in error traces as mentioned in comment by david above. I don't get why you added parenthesis around onSuccess, I don't see it making any difference. Good link abour nfe.

Comment: thats why i included the other link, which says the javascript you want is illegal ( though some browsers may support it)

Comment: The javascript he wants isn't 'illegal', it's just a named function expression.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to create named functions in CoffeeScript is to use `class`:

```
someFunction 42,
  class onSuccess
    constructor: ->
  class onFailure
    constructor: ->
```

Comment: That generates some pretty interesting code. http://jsfiddle.net/jyro/cJgzD/ far from what I need though.